# Problema ao exibir galeria camera cordova ios

Tags: ios, apache-cordova, ionic

Estou utilizando o plugin cordova `$cordovaCamera.getPicture` e ao abrir a galeria de fotos no *ios* está quebrando a *label*  deste jeito: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Primeiro : Estou com o a linguagem do aparelho em português e está aparecendo em inglês

Segundo: As letras está com a separação por "_" e não por espaço.
Alguém já teve este problema?

versão cordova 6.1.1, ionic 1.7.14, ios 9.3

Trecho do código

```
var options = { quality: 100,
                        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URL,
                        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                        allowEdit: true,
                        encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                        targetWidth: 400,
                        targetHeight: 400,
                        popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                        saveToPhotoAlbum: false };
```